# Not sure why this is in my <head> on all my pages.

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, fonts

I am using Divi by Elegant Themes. When I inspect the  in chrome I see [http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9oOk.jpg) I am not sure why this font is getting called. I am using the default font which is open sans. I am planning on pushing my site over to HTTPS and I am concerned about this in my head causing a "mixed content" error. Any insight about why this is happening and what I can do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first question would obviously be: have you checked the Elegant Themes site for docs that explain how to control which fonts get loaded. If so, can you update your post with some information on what you found, and how that didn't help? If not, that would be step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the fonts are being loaded by Divi then switching to HTTPS won't be an issue. The function to load Google Fonts (`et_builder_enqueue_font()`) can be found on line 1265 of 'includes/builder/functions.php' inside the theme folder. Keep in mind this could differ based on version.

The function checks the protocol and makes an appropriate request to Google Fonts:

```
$protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';

...

... $query_args, "$protocol://fonts.googleapis.com/css" )
```

Roboto could be queued up by the theme depending on the customisation options used.

It's worth pointing out that Divi may not necessarily be the culprit. Check your plugins too.